# Loop through Rows and click

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I've the below HTML table.

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Link 1</td>
            <td>Archieved</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Link 2</td>
            <td>Terminated</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Link 3</td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Link 4</td>
            <td>Archieved</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here basically i want to loop through all the rows and click only if the content in second row doesn't contain `Terminated`.

In XSLT i use to use `xsl:for-each select` but in Selenium I'm unable to understand how to do this. Please let me know how i can click on the rows that doesn't contain `Terminated`.

Thanks

Comment: What selenium language bindings are you using?

Comment: Hi @alecxe, I'm using Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may filter out rows not containing "Terminated" with a single XPath expression:

```
//tr[td[2] != 'Terminated']
```

Here is how you may loop through the elements matching a selector:

```
for(WebElement row: driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[td[2] != 'Terminated']"))) {
    // do smth with a row
}
```

Comment: But i need to loop through all the rows and get some data

Comment: @user3872094 okay, added an example, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can loop through all rows, click the ones that do not match "Terminated" as text and do whatever you like with the other rows:

```
List<WebElement> allRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tr"))

for (WebElement row : allRows) {
    if (!row.findElement(By.xpath("./td[2]")).getText().contains("Terminated")) {
        row.click();
    }
    // get whatever you need from the rows here
}
```